# How can I show all data records on Chartkick without any distinct?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, chartkick

I'm trying to visualize my data using Chartkick. Here is my data:

```
data = [["A1", 62979], ["A1", -47419], ["A1", 15560],["S1", 0],["S1", 0],["S1", 0],["S1", 0],["S1", 0],["S1", 0],["A1", 0],["A1", 0],["A1", 0],["A1", 0],["A1", 0],["A1", 0],["A1", 0],["A1", 0],["A1", 0],["L1", 0],["L1", 41697],["L1", 41697]]
```

and when I tried to print it on my chart using this code:

```
column_chart data
```

I got this output:

[image: this]

I just got the distinct record. All I want is, the chart should print A1 with the value 62979, A1 with the value -47419, other A1 with the value 15560, S1 with the value 0, other S1 with the value 0 and so on. So, my question is, how can I print all records of my data into chart without any distinct value on X axis?

Comment: that's not how a column chart works, values with the same key must be grouped or you have to use multiple series. However your case seems to make no senss to be put in a chart...

Comment: I see, thanks for your help @DoktorOSwaldo